# Extracting value from cells in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
2019-02-12  24;26;28    18;20;22    11;12;13    11;12;13    
2019-02-13  24;26;28    18;20;22    11;12;13    11;12;13
```

I want to extract the middle values each column of this dataframe. The data is the index and the string of numbers are the column values. How can I do this using pandas?

The desired output would be:

```
2019-02-12  26  20  12  12  
2019-02-13  26  20  12  12
```

Comment: Pandas can do it through the `str` attribute of a string column that allow to apply regex operations to all the values. But IMHO, the cleaning of such values should occur before the values enter the dataframe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data preparation in the format you have mentioned..

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df.loc[0] = ['2019-02-12' , '24;26;28'  ,' 18;20;22',    '11;12;13',    '11;12;13']
df.loc[1] = ['2019-02-13',  '24;26;28',    '18;20;22',    '11;12;13',    '11;12;13']
df ['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df
                   A          B         C         D
Date                                               
2019-02-12  24;26;28   18;20;22  11;12;13  11;12;13
2019-02-13  24;26;28   18;20;22  11;12;13  11;12;13
```

First split the values on ';' and then get the values at index 1 for the splitted values.

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col]= df[col].str.split(';').str[1].astype(str)
    
df
             A   B   C   D
Date                      
2019-02-12  26  20  12  12
2019-02-13  26  20  12  12
```

Now you can use `aggregate` to join these

```
df['Result'] = df.agg(' '.join, axis=1)
df
             A   B   C   D       Result
Date                                   
2019-02-12  26  20  12  12  26 20 12 12
2019-02-13  26  20  12  12  26 20 12 12
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply it to all columns except of the first, you can do:

**Sample:**

```
          date    value1      value2      value3      value4
0   2019-02-12  24;26;28    18;20;22    11;12;13    11;12;13
1   2019-02-13  24;26;28    18;20;22    11;12;13    11;12;13
```

**Solution:**

```
df.loc[:, df.columns[1:]] = df.loc[:, df.columns[1:]].apply(lambda x: x.str.split(';').str[1])
```

**Output:**

```
          date  value1  value2  value3  value4
0   2019-02-12      26      20      12      12
1   2019-02-13      26      20      12      12
```

If you want to use it for certain columns, you can pass a list of their names instead of taking all except of the first:

```
df.loc[:, [list_of_columns]]
```

If date is your index column and you want to apply it for the rest, don't use [1:]:

```
 df.loc[:, df.columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the date column is the index, meaning that the DataFrame can be build from:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1: {pd.Timestamp('2019-02-12 00:00:00'): '24;26;28',
                       pd.Timestamp('2019-02-13 00:00:00'): '24;26;28'},
                   2: {pd.Timestamp('2019-02-12 00:00:00'): '18;20;22', 
                       pd.Timestamp('2019-02-13 00:00:00'): '18;20;22'},
                   3: {pd.Timestamp('2019-02-12 00:00:00'): '11;12;13', 
                       pd.Timestamp('2019-02-13 00:00:00'): '11;12;13'},
                   4: {pd.Timestamp('2019-02-12 00:00:00'): '11;12;13',
                       pd.Timestamp('2019-02-13 00:00:00'): '11;12;13'}})
```

then you can *clean* it with:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r'.*;(.*);.*', r'\1'))
```

It will give as expected:

```
             1   2   3   4
2019-02-12  26  20  12  12
2019-02-13  26  20  12  12
```

But IMHO, this kind of processing should occur before loading the data into the dataframe, or at load time. The sooner the better...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It only returns NaN values in my code, do you have any idea why that is?

Comment: @Thomma **I** provided reproducible data, **you** did not. If you do not say how I can build your dataframe, I will not be able to guess.